# Many-to-many hibernate xml configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have such DB relationship.
[image: db scheme]

I want to have many-to-many relationship. Between `PLAYER` and `PRIVILEGE`. Could you please help me to fix my .xml configs.

**Expected result:**
I want to be able to execute: `String hql = "from Player as p right outer join p.privilages as priv";`

**Actual:**
So far I get:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK8CD18EE134F64423:PLAYER
>   [ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key
>   (PRIVILAGE [ID,PRIVILAGE])

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Privilage" table="PRIVILAGE">
        <id name="id" type="int" >
            <column name="ID"  precision="5" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <set name="players" table="PLAYER"
             inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
            <key>
                <column name="ID"/>
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="model.Player">
                <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>

        <property name="privilage" type="string">
            <column name="PRIVILAGE" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<class name="model.Player" table="PLAYER">
    <id name="playerId" type="int" >
        <column name="ID" precision="5" scale="0"/>
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">PLAYER_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <set name="privilages" table="PRIVILAGE"
         inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="ID"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="model.Privilage">
            <column name="PRIVILAGE" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
    <!-- ... -->
</class>
```

Comment: I see `inverse=false` for both the entities in the <set> tag. Only one of them needs to be false and other should be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reference your many-to-many relationship table called PLAYER_PRIV:

```
<set name="privilages" table="PLAYER_PRIV"
     inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="ID"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="model.Privilage">
        <column name="PRIV_ID" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

and

```
<set name="players" table="PLAYER_PRIV"
     inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="ID"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="model.Player">
        <column name="PLAYER_ID" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the wrong association table name and its columns.

1) The association table for both sides is the same (`PLAYER_PRIV`):

```
<set name="privilages" table="PLAYER_PRIV"
    ...
</set>

<set name="players" table="PLAYER_PRIV"
    ...
</set>
```

2) Columns in `Privilage` mappings:

```
<key>
   <column name="PRIV_ID"/>
</key>
<many-to-many entity-name="model.Player">
   <column name="PLAYER_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-many>
```

In `Player` mappings it is the opposite:

```
<key>
   <column name="PLAYER_ID"/>
</key>
<many-to-many entity-name="model.Privilage">
   <column name="PRIV_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-many>
```

3) Other than that, you have to pick one side to be `inverse`. From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional):

> If the association is bidirectional, one side has to be the owner and
>   one side has to be the inverse end (ie. it will be ignored when
>   updating the relationship values in the association table).

4) You probably don't want to use `cascade=all` in many-to-many associations, because when removing a privilege you probably don't want to remove all players to which the privilege is granted.

Comment: Thanks for answer will have a chance to check and accept it at the 11th of Jan. Happy New Year

Comment: I get an exception: `Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK8CD18EE134E8E09F:PLAYER [PLAYER_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (PLAYER [PRIV_ID,PLAYER_ID])`